# AS NET MVC How to keep track of checkbox value using a variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, jscript

I have a following situation.
I have a variable bOk into a HTML page. I'd like to update this variable every time a checkbox.checked property was changed.
I think the best way should be using jscript but I don't know how to start this.
That is the reason I did not put a code in this question.
Is there a way to somebody to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Using the onclick event, you can get the state of the checkbox with jQuery whenever it is clicked.

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-id").onclick = function() {
    var bOk = $("#checkbox-id").is(":checked")
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("checkbox-id").onclick = function() {
    var bOk = $("#checkbox-id").is(":checked")
    alert(bOk);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="chkok" type="checkbox" />Tick
@{var BOK = "Hi..";}
<input type="hidden" value=@BOK id="hdnbok">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#chkok').click(function ()
{ 
alert($("#hdnbok").val());
}) 
});
```